# Is there a name for this mutual information-like quantity based on JS divergence

Tags: information-theory

For two random variables X and Y, let us consider the following quantity
$$I'(X,Y)=\mathrm{JS}(p(X,Y)||p(X)p(Y)),$$
where $\mathrm{JS}(\cdot || \cdot)$ denotes the Jensen–Shannon (JS) divergence.

This quantity is similar to the mutual information defined by the KL divergence, and $I'(X,Y)=0$ if X and Y are independent. Is there a name for this quantity or any related analysis on it?

Answer (score 1):

This measure is defined in [a 2019 paper](https://www.eng.biu.ac.il/goldbej/files/2019/03/Yaniv_icassp_2019.pdf)* as Jensen-Shannon Mutual
information (JSMI). They present it as something they propose, so at least according to their knowledge, it wasn't used prior.

$\ast$ Goldberger, Jacob, and Yaniv Opochinsky. "Information-bottleneck Based on the Jensen-Shannon Divergence with Applications to Pairwise Clustering." IEEE International Conference on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing (ICASSP). IEEE, 2019.